# How to call a boost::function object with all arguments bound

Tags: c++, boost, c++03

I've been [reading up](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) on `boost::function` and `boost::bind`, however, I can't seem to figure out a "good way" to call a `boost` function if all the arguments are bound (I think that's the right terminology).  Below is an untested MCVE (copying-and-pasting my real code is not ideal).

```
#include "boost/function.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void func(void* args)
{
  int* myInt = static_cast<int*>(args);
  if (myInt != NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "myInt = " << *myInt << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "args is NULL" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int myInt1 = 5;
  int myInt2 = 45;

  boost::function<void(void* args)> myFunc = boost::bind(&func, &myInt1);

  // here's my problem,, how do I call myFunc?
  myFunc();  // this does not compile due to missing arguments
  myFunc;    // this is essentially a no-op. The function doesn't execute,
             // and if I put a breakpoint here, it either goes to the next
             // line or I get a warning that no executable code exists here

  // after some experimentation, I realized I can do this and it works
  myFunc(NULL);  // this prints out "myInt = 5"

  // this also prints out "myInt = 5"
  boost::bind(&func, &myInt1)();

  // finally, this prints out "myInt = 5" as well
  myFunc(&myInt2);

  return 0;
}
```

So my question is, what's the preferred/right way to call `myFunc`?  I've successfully called functions with the `_1`, `_2`, etc argument placeholders by passing in the appropriate arguments.. maybe in practice there are placeholders almost all the time? `myFunc(NULL)` works, but it seems silly to me that I must essentially make up arguments if I've already bound them (and what I pass in doesn't matter anyway).  In my real code, I actually want to call `myFunc` in a different function (so `boost::bind(&func, &myInt1)();` isn't an option), and I'm doing so inside an object of a class, so I hope the example I've provided exhibits identical behavior to what I'm seeing in my real code.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and c++11 or later cannot be used.

Comment: The type for `myFunc`is wrong, it should be `boost::function<void()> myFunc`, then just `myFunc()`.

Comment: or `auto myFunc`.

Comment: Probably not `auto myFunc` for C++03

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function object with "all parameters bound" has no parameters, so its type would be `boost::function<void()>`. You need

```
boost::function<void()> myFunc = boost::bind(&func, &myInt1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A better type for your `myFunc` variable would be `boost::function<void()>`, because with all arguments of the original `func` bound, no arguments are really needed to call the resulting wrapper.

```
boost::function<void()> myFunc = boost::bind(&func, &myInt1);
```

This would in fact allow you to call the function with just:

```
myFunc();
```

---

But the reason the compiler allowed the `boost::function<void(void*)>` type there is that the result of a `boost::bind` call can be called with more arguments than necessary if you choose to, and extra arguments are just ignored.  One thing this does is makes situations like this a bit more consistent:

```
void f(int, int);
// g1 acts the same as f:
boost::function<void(int, int)> g1 = boost::bind(f, _1, _2);
// g2 swaps the order of arguments when calling f:
boost::function<void(int, int)> g2 = boost::bind(f, _2, _1);
// g3 ignores its first argument and passes the second to f twice:
boost::function<void(int, int)> g3 = boost::bind(f, _2, _2);
// g4 ignores its second argument and passes the first to f twice:
boost::function<void(int, int)> g4 = boost::bind(f, _1, _1);
```

In the `g4` initialization, we can say the `bind` expression is just another bound function that can be called with exactly two `int` arguments, because it doesn't use any placeholders with position larger than 2.  It can also be called with just one argument since `_2` itself isn't ever used either, but that doesn't make the above false.

So similarly, in your code initializing `boost::function<void(void*)>`, the compiler accepts the completely bound `bind` expression as something which can validly be called with one argument, since it doesn't use any placeholders with position larger than 1.  Though since in fact it doesn't use the placeholder `_1` with position exactly 1 either, the `void*` input when used in that way just ends up being ignored.